# TFS REST API Get items that failed to build

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

Someone know the way to get projects that failed to build,
through the TFS REST API?

Comment: A quick google turned up [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#buildstatus), which hints at using a `resultFilter` of `failed`. In future you may want to take the SO [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Asking "somebody knows X?" Could have a valid but not useful yes/no answer. Do some research, try some code, and if you get a problem come back with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the build logs with [Build - Get Build Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20log) Rest API. You need to know which log id is the build log (if you have few tasks so each task has a log), so you can  check all the available logs with [Build - Get Build Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs) Rest API, then iterate them and check the what is the build. after you have the log you can search and filter the errors.

A small example with PowerShell:

```
$collection = "http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/collection"
$project = "team-project"
$buildId = 10

#"api-version=4.1" is for TFS 2018, for other versions you need to change the number
$logsUrl = "$collection/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/lgos?api-version=4.1"
$logs = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $logsUrl -Method Get -UseDeafultCredntials -ContentType application/json

$buildLog = ""
ForEach($log in $logs.value)
{
    $urlLog = "$collection/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/logs/$($log.id)?api-version=4.1"
    $logDetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlLog -Method Get -UseDefaultCredntials -ContentType application/json
    if($logDetails.Contains("msbuild"))
    {
         $buildLog = $logDetails
         break
    }
}
# Now you have the logs in your hand and you can find in which projects have errors
```

If you want to do it with C# you can call the Rest API with `HttpClient`:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDeafultCredntials = true } )
{
     string url = "the-url-from-above-powershell-script";
     var method = new HttpMethod("GET");
     var reqeust = new HttpRequestMessage(mehtod,url);
     var result = await client.SendAsync(rqeuest);
}
// In this way you get the Rest API response, so you need to it once for the logs, iterate them to get each log and then filter the errors.
```